# How to install pygame, cv2, anaconda, pip etc to any one version of python in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, pygame, ubuntu-14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I guess different versions of python are pre-installed in Ubuntu 14.04. Right now when I type 'python' in terminal it opens python 2.7.11, but I guess the default version of Ubuntu 14.04 is 2.7.6. When I type `/usr/bin/python` it opens the default version. I know this can be done with making aliases. The real problem is, I have installed pygame, cv2 (that is for image processing) using apt-get. These are installed for default version of python i.e python 2.7.6. Also I have installed anaconda with python 2.7.11 using pip, but again 'pip' and anaconda are installed for 2.7.11. I know python 3 is also pre-installed there but I don't use it. Also I have no python version installed in `user/local/bin`.Now I want to know why this problem is occurring? How can I fix this now? Also how to import all the libraries for one python version(either default or another) and how to use it? How to configure my settings so that I would not have any problem in future?

Comment: Python will only import libraries for the major version it's using. Python 3 libraries installed with pip aren't available to the Python 2 interpreter. This is because pip places the libraries in a specific destination for a specific version.

Run the code:
`import sys`
`print (sys.version)`

Comment: Thanks bennet. So what is the solution now? How to install pip and anaconda for default version. Because when i install them using using apt-get. It says unable to locate package pip.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `easy_install` installed you can run

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

to install pip. As far as installing Anaconda goes, try using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/installing-anaconda-python-on-ubuntu) stack overflow question's answer. If you can't get that to work comment explaining the issue.

Comment: I did it. But it installed anaconda to python 2.7.11. Did it happen because i have python 2.7.11 as aliased as 'python'? Should i first alias 2.7.6 as 'python'?

Comment: If there's an issue between 2.7.6 and 2.7.11 aliasing Python might be an easy fix.

Comment: Yes i aliased the default python version as 'python' and installed everything to that version only.. It is done now.. thanks!!!

Comment: Excellent, so it was just a matter of lining up the versions. If you would like to mark my question as the answer please do so, so that future programmers with your problem can find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to thanks Bennet for responding to my question so that I was able to figure out what the problem was. Actually the problem was with aliasing. When I installed cv2 or pygame using apt-get, they were installed for default version but when I installed any package by downloading the installer first (like I installed anaconda), it was installed for python 2.7.11 because 'python' was aliased for this version(that is 2.7.11). So, basically make sure that the default version for which you want to install everything is the one which is aliased as 'python', and everything goes fine. I aliased 'python' for the default version and then installed anaconda via installer and now it has been installed default version.